# How can I make an if statement that recognizes whether or not my input appears in a list?

Tags: python, list, if-statement, input

That is what I have so far and it doesn't work, I am new to Python so sorry if there is a really obvious mistake that I don't see :)

```
Quotes = ['Iron and Blood' , 'No Quote Available' ]   
Blood=Quotes[0]
Else=Quotes[1]

Name = raw_input('Who do you want this humble AI to quote?')
if Name == Bismark:
    print(Blood)
```

Comment: Is `Bismark` the list? Or is it a string? if it's a list, you should use `if name in list:`.

Comment: Welcome to SO :) For future reference: Please add the error to your post. Just saying 'it doesn't work' makes it hard to tell where you are struggling. Most of the time reading (and understanding) the error helps a great deal. Also not posting the error might get your question closed as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

You are missing quotes around Bismark if you want to treat it as a string. You want that, because the `raw_input` function returns the text the user entered as a string against which you are comparing. This should do the trick:

```
Quotes = ['Iron and Blood' , 'No Quote Available' ]   
Blood=Quotes[0]
Else=Quotes[1]

Name = raw_input('Who do you want this humble AI to quote?')
if Name == 'Bismark':
    print(Blood)
```

That said there are some better and or more 'pythonic' ways to do this. This one uses a dictionary to store quotes:

```
quotes = {
    'Bismark': 'Iron and Blood',
    'pep8': 'Variable names should be lower case to make them distinguishable from class names.', 
}
not_found = 'No Quote Available'

# this would be just input for python3
name = raw_input('Who do you want this humble AI to quote?')

try:
    print(quotes[name])
except KeyError:
    print(not_found)
```

This allows you to add new quotes to the dictionary without adding an if-statement every time.